# dhtmlxCombo help on wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, combobox, dhtmlx

### *EDIT: I FOUND THE SOLUTION TO MY QUESTION. ANSWER BELOW*

---

i'm trying to implement a ComboBox on my wordpress install but for some reason i can't get it to work.

this is what i've done so far:

- downloaded dhtmlx (the whole suite) from
  dhtmlx.com/docs/download.shtml
- -copied the codebase,skin and sources    files to my server (example.com )

added a function on the
   function.php file of my childtheme(theme X) (wrote the absolute link
   for reference purposes)

```
add_action('wp_head','add_combobox_header');
function add_combobox_header() {
    echo'
    <script src="http://example.com/dhtmlx/codebase/dhtmlx.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/dhtmlx/skins/web/dhtmlx.css"/>
<script async>
        var myCombo, myCombo2;
        function doOnLoad() {
            myCombo = new dhtmlXCombo("combo_zone", "combo", 230);
            myCombo.load("http://example.com/dhtmlx/combo_group.php?mode=state");
            myCombo.enableFilteringMode(true);
            //
            myCombo2 = new dhtmlXCombo("combo_zone2", "combo2", 230);
            myCombo2.enableFilteringMode(true);
            myCombo2.disable();
            //
            myCombo.attachEvent("onChange", function(value){
                myCombo2.clearAll();
                myCombo2.setComboValue(null);
                myCombo2.setComboText("");
                if (value == null) {
                    myCombo2.disable();
                } else {
                    myCombo2.enable();
                    myCombo2.load("http://example.com/dhtmlx/region/region_country.xml");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

';
}
```

4) copied the following code on a raw content module (there are thousands of plugins for this. you can also add this directly on your child theme if you find it more appropriate):

```
<div onload="doOnLoad();">
    <h3>Select state</h3>
    <div id="combo_zone" style="width:230px;"></div>
    <br>
    <h3>Select city</h3>
    <div id="combo_zone2" style="width:230px;"></div>
</div>
```

but i got this result:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljxJ3.png)

I can see everything BUT the combobox and i have no idea what did i do wrong (i don't get any errors on my error_log or while inspecting the element in firefox or chrome).

I've tried everything but i always get the same result so at this point i can only hope some of you guys point me to the right direction or at least tell me what am i doing wrong cause i already ran out of ideas.

P.s: I also tried building a shortcode for it, getting the same result.
this is just the last code i tried, which is practically a copy-paste of the example shown in the official site: [Grouping Combo - dhtmlXCombo](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/samples/08_advanced/01_grouping_combos.html#code)

Comment: are you sure the headers are loading correctly? did you check the dev console on Chrome?

Comment: yes, i verified and the headers are loading, correctly. the console doesn't give me any error, nor do i get any error on the error_log. and the headers appear normally while inspecting the site with the console in chrome,

Comment: one thing i noticed is that the site is actually slowers since i add the doOnLoad() function to the header. maybe that's a clue that something's not working properly? at first i thought i could have been the skin, but now i believe the problem resides on the loading of the json, php file or xml, that have all the options in it, that for some reason i cannot reads them, thus deactivating itself. but i don't find any error in the code :/

Comment: Recommend you to open topic in dhx forum:

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onload="doOnLoad();">
```

div does not have onload event, in dhtmlx demos it attached to body element. you can try the following code:

```
dhtmlxEvent(window, function(){
var myCombo = new dhtmlXCombo("combo_zone", "combo", 230);
...
})
```

Comment: yeah, my bad hehe. however i managed to fix the problem. i had to use a different approach (i'll post the answer in a moment). 

thanks for the help, anyways!!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading and trying i managed to fix the problem! and i want to share my solution with the community.

Before i begin dharing my solution, i want to tell you that the first code i used was an example code of how to Group combos, you can find it in [the official library site](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/samples/08_advanced/01_grouping_combos.html)

**Let's begin:**

1) I added the headers to the  tag of my theme. to do so i went to: root/wp-content/themes/your-theme (using ftp) and then edited the    **functions.php** file adding this function:

```
//-----ADD HEADERS FOR COMBOBOX ---------------
add_action('wp_head','add_combobox_header');
function add_combobox_header() {
    wp_enqueue_style('dhtmlx', 'http://facilecitta.it/dhtmlx/codebase/dhtmlxcombo_dhx_web.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('dhtmlx', 'http://facilecitta.it/dhtmlx/codebase/dhtmlx.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dhtmlxjs', 'http://facilecitta.it/dhtmlx/codebase/dhtmlx.js','', '', true );
}
```

**NOTE:** 
*The dhtmlxcombo_dhx_web.css is just a skin for the combobox so you can either have dhtmlx.css for the default skin or the dhtmlxcombo_dhx_web.css which is better for web apps* (i added both here ONLY for REFERENCE purposes  ***you don't need to have both***)

2) Then i added the script of the original code (see link above) right before the  tag so it wouldn't interfere with the loading of the site.

```
//-----SCRIPT FOR COMBOBOX-----------------
add_action('wp_footer', 'combobox_js_code_after_body');
function combobox_js_code_after_body() { 
?>
<script>

  var myCombo, myCombo2;
  function doOnLoad() {
    myCombo = new dhtmlXCombo("combo_zone", "combo", 230);
    myCombo.load("http://your-site.com/dhtmlx/options.xml");
    myCombo.enableFilteringMode(true);
    //
    myCombo2 = new dhtmlXCombo("combo_zone2", "combo2", 230);
    myCombo2.enableFilteringMode(true);
    myCombo2.disable();
    //
    myCombo.attachEvent("onChange", function(value){
      myCombo2.clearAll();
      myCombo2.setComboValue(null);
      myCombo2.setComboText("");
      if (value == null) {
        myCombo2.disable();
      } else {
        myCombo2.enable();
        myCombo2.load("http://your-site.com/dhtmlx/options2.xml");
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<?php 
}
```

3) i now wanted to add the "onload" attribute to the body tag of my theme, so i went to my theme's directory, edited header.php (in my case) and changed this code:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

into this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> onload="doOnLoad();">
```

and then just added the remaining code on the raw content module of my theme:

```
<h3>Select state</h3>
    <div class="combo_info">California for example</div>
    <div id="combo_zone" style="width:230px;"></div>
    <br>
    <h3>Select city</h3>
    <div id="combo_zone2" style="width:230px;"></div>
```

### **AND VOILA! now i had a nice combobox in my site =D**

Note: I'd like to thank the guys at themeco, who gave me useful information that helped me find the right solution for my problem!